# Kotlin - Guava's Iterables.transform equivalent?

Tags: arraylist, kotlin, collections, transform

Please look at this Java code:

```
calendarEvents = Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.transform(
    wastageSchedule, item -> new BaseCalendarEvent(
        item.getWastageTypeName(),
        item.getWastageTypeName(),
        item.getLocation(),
        ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorWastageItem),
        item.getStartDate(),
        item.getEndDate(),
        true
    )
));
```

It just transforms `ArrayList<CalendarEvent>` into `ArrayList<BaseCalendarEvent>`. Is there any equivalent to it in Kotlin? I looked into Kotlin documentation, but I did not find anything like `transform`, can you provide any tip?

Comment: What about `List.map()`?

Comment: I recommend [Learning Kotlin by Example](https://play.kotlinlang.org/byExample/05_Collections/04_map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin has `map` extension function on Iterables. E. g.

```
calendarEvents = wastageSchedule.map { item ->
    BaseCalendarEvent(...)
}
```

Comment: Well this seems to be what I was looking for, thanks